# Why does my Eevee render look completely different then my viewport render?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I set up a 3d-Room with a hologramm for rendering. I was nearly finished and rendered a Test Picture in Eevee for the colorgrading. But then I saw this Picture as render result! I tried rendering in Cycles too, but it looked the same. I attached some Screenshots of my Settings. Does anybody know why this happened?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english

[image][image: These are my render settings]

Comment: Hi, welcome! To help others to understand what is happening, please try to better describe how you set your viewport (interactive) and rendering (F12) settings, add details since there is always the issue!

Comment: I added a Picture of my settings now. I this what you meant?

Comment: it is better, but I would also detail or show how viewport rendering is set, probably, since you're comparing it with F12 rendering. Or, if this issue happens only with this particular light effect... and how it is set up in materials/nodes... or, even share your file (or a similar test one) - preferably using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and pasting in your answer the provided link. But you only are the judge of how much clear is your question :)